# jQuery: Hide parent of object with same text as selector on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a menu where I want (because of specific dynamic content I can't use classes or ID's) to hide all items that hasn't the same text as the menu-selector.

HTML:

```
<ul>
 <li class="dropDown">
 <li class="galSub"><a href="#">Alla</a></li>
 <li class="galSub"><a href="#">NorrlandsOperan</a></li>
 <li class="galSub"><a href="#">Norrdans</a></li>
 <li class="galSub"><a href="#">Estrad Norr</a></li>
 <li class="galSub"><a href="#">Piteå Kammaropera</a>  </li>
</ul>

<div class="box boxImg col2">
   <h3>Figaro</h3>
    <h4 class="prodEns">NorrlandsOperan</h4>
</div>
<div class="box boxImg col2 ">
   <h3>A la Carte</h3>
   <h4 class="prodEns">Norrdans</h4>
</div>
<div class="box boxImg col2">
   <h3>Porta</h3>
   <h4 class="prodEns">Estrad Norr</h4>
</div>
<div class="box boxImg col2">
   <h3>A la Carte</h3>
   <h4 class="prodEns">Piteå Kammaropera</h4>
</div>
```

JQuery:

```
var galLi = $('.galSub a');
var prodItm = $('.boxImg'); 
var prodEns = $('.prodEns');

galLi.click(function(e){
    var refLink = $(this);
    e.preventDefault();
    if (prodEns.text() == refLink.text()) {
    $('this').parent().siblings(prodItm).hide();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll opt for [.filter()](https://api.jquery.com/filter) over [:contains](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) as it can return partial matches

```js
var galLi = $('.galSub');
var boxImgs = $('.boxImg');

galLi.click(function(e){
    var text = $(this).text().trim();
    e.preventDefault();
    boxImgs.filter(function(){
        return $(this).find('.prodEns').text().trim() == text;
    }).toggle();//use toggle if you want to hide and show, else just use hide()
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
 <li class="dropDown">
 <li class="galSub"><a href="#">Alla</a></li>
 <li class="galSub"><a href="#">NorrlandsOperan</a></li>
 <li class="galSub"><a href="#">Norrdans</a></li>
 <li class="galSub"><a href="#">Estrad Norr</a></li>
 <li class="galSub"><a href="#">Piteå Kammaropera</a>  </li>
</ul>

<div class="box boxImg col2">
   <h3>Figaro</h3>
    <h4 class="prodEns">NorrlandsOperan</h4>
</div>
<div class="box boxImg col2 ">
   <h3>A la Carte</h3>
   <h4 class="prodEns">Norrdans</h4>
</div>
<div class="box boxImg col2">
   <h3>Porta</h3>
   <h4 class="prodEns">Estrad Norr</h4>
</div>
<div class="box boxImg col2">
   <h3>A la Carte</h3>
   <h4 class="prodEns">Piteå Kammaropera</h4>
</div>
```

Comment: Good point! I wish the OP would vote or accept so we can be sure this is what he wanted. Your way is definately bettter

Answer (score 1):

Try this out http://jsfiddle.net/b2d8ncny/1/

```
var galLi = $('.galSub a');
var prodItm = $('.boxImg'); 
var prodEns = $('.prodEns');

galLi.click(function(e){
    var refLink = $(this);
    e.preventDefault();
    prodItm.hide();
    prodEns.each(function(i,val){
         if ($(val).text().trim() == refLink.text().trim()) {
                $(val).closest(".boxImg").show();      
         }
    })


})
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
$('.prodEns:not(:contains('+refLink.text()+'))').each(function(){
    $(this).parent().siblings(prodItm).hide();
});
```